# Falta de tradução na sinalização de comentários

Tags: bug, tradução

Enquanto ia sinalizar um comentário, o diálogo surgiu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso está presente no SOpt e no Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Não é uma resposta, mas acho que os links ficam melhor dispostas neste formato do que colocando tudo em comentários.

As strings estão listadas abaixo:

[Why are you flagging this comment?](https://pt.traducir.win/string/6454)

[It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.](https://pt.traducir.win/string/674) 
[This comment attacks a person or group. Learn more in our [Code of Conduct]($url$).](https://pt.traducir.win/string/7900)

[It's unfriendly or unkind.](https://pt.traducir.win/string/9723) 
[This comment is rude or condescending. Learn more in our [Code of Conduct]($url$).](https://pt.traducir.win/string/7796)

[It's no longer needed.](https://pt.traducir.win/string/1482) 
[This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.](https://pt.traducir.win/string/8173)

[Something else.](https://pt.traducir.win/string/8331) 
[A problem not listed above. Try to be as specific as possible.](https://pt.traducir.win/string/72)